# How to define instance class with platform node.js?

Tags: node.js, configuration, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to define the instance class for my app.
I want to use the switch between F1 and F2 to check app performance according to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#instance_classes)

However, I can't find in the nodeJS documentation if this is possible. The Python documentation explains [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref) how to use instance_class variable in the app.yaml.

Is it also supported with nodeJS ?
Are the defaults the same (F1 for automatic scaling and B2 for basic and manual) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With NodeJS it's not a standart environment but a flexible. The configuration is not same.

You can refer to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#resource-settings) to configure your application's ressources.

ie.

```
# app.yaml
resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 2.3
  disk_size_gb: 10
  volumes:
  - name: ramdisk1
    volume_type: tmpfs
    size_gb: 0.5
```

Comment: So I have to define the specific resources and than calculate the price accordingly ?

Comment: Yes, but you can easily calculate with https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/

Comment: Any free quotas for the flexible environment ? I can only find those for standard environment